# How can i improve this code? Also i was wondering why every time i run this piece of code that the contents in the file were always overwritten?

Tags: java, encryption

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {
//This function will decode the value of the XOR binary back
  public static void decodingXorCipher(String[] XorApplied) throws IOException
  {
    String binaryValue ; 
    char cTemp; 
    String szOutput = ""; 
    System.out.println("Converting Binary to ASCII Text...") ;
    for(int q = 0 ; q < XorApplied.length ; q++)
    {
      binaryValue = XorApplied[q] ; 
      //This is the method that has converted binary back into ASCII text
      cTemp = (binaryToChar(binaryValue)); 
      szOutput = szOutput + cTemp ; 
    }
    //Stores the encrypted message to a file
    System.out.println(szOutput) ; 
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("eMessage.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(szOutput) ; 
    writer.close();
  }

//Adds the XOR gate to the cipher
 public static void XorCipher(String[] binaryArray , String[] keyBinaryArray)
  {
    //Have a placement value of value0 = 0 to pad the binary to 8 bit binary
    //One by one store the data needed from array into a temporary variable
    //Split each digit from the data, and store it into a different variable
    //Two For Loops one runs on the length of the message (binaryArray.length) and another on the length of the binary data (8)
    //compare the digits at the given address and apply the XOR Cipher
    //0 and 0 gives 0
    //0 and 1 gives 1
    //1 and 0 gives 1
    //1 and 1 gives 0
    System.out.println("Applying the XOR gate...") ; 
    String iTemp; 
    String iTempBinary ;     
    int Length ; 
    String szFinished = "" ; 
    String[] XorApplied = new String [binaryArray.length] ; 
    //This loop will control the length of the message being encrypted
    for(int a = 0 ; a < binaryArray.length ; a ++)
    {
      iTemp = binaryArray[a] ;

      iTempBinary = keyBinaryArray[a] ; 
      Length = iTemp.length() ; 
      szFinished = "" ; 
      //Loop used for the indiviual characters in one 8 bit binary setup
      //Used to apply the XOR gate to both of the binaries
       for(int b = 0 ; b < 8 ; b++) 
       { 
          if(iTemp.charAt(b) == iTempBinary.charAt(b))
          {
            szFinished = (szFinished + "0") ;
          }
          else
          {
            szFinished = (szFinished + "1") ; 
          }
       }
//Each of these is then stored into an array
       XorApplied[a] = szFinished ;
     }
      //This was needed as it was throwing an IOException
      try {
            decodingXorCipher(XorApplied) ; 
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error") ; 
        } 

  }  

  //Find binary values of each indiviual character in the message
  public static void findBinary(char[] keyArray , char[] messageArray) 
  {
    //Creates new arrays that are the same length of the message and key
    String [] binaryArray = new String[messageArray.length];
    String [] keyBinaryArray = new String[keyArray.length];
    String iTemp;  
    String keyTemp ;
    System.out.println("Converting Data to Binary...") ; 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < messageArray.length ; i++) 
     { 
        //Each element in the array is being converted to a binary value
        iTemp =  String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(messageArray[i])).replace(' ', '0');
        //The String value is being converted into an int data type

        //This is being stored into an array
        binaryArray[i] = iTemp ; 
        //This binary element is being stored into an array
       // System.out.println(binaryArray[i]) ; 
     }
    System.out.println();

    //Loop used to find ot the binary values of the key and store that into an array
    for(int k = 0 ; k < keyArray.length ;  k ++)
     {
     //Finds the binary values
       keyTemp =  String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(keyArray[k])).replace(' ', '0');          
     //Stores the int data type into an array
       keyBinaryArray[k] = keyTemp ; 
       //System.out.println(keyBinaryArray[k]) ; 
     }
    System.out.println("Data has been converted to Binary...") ;
    XorCipher(binaryArray , keyBinaryArray) ; 

  }

  //Taking all the variables in
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
     String key = "" ;
     String userMessage ;
     int iRandom , iSum ; 
     char letter ;
     String szBinary;  
     //Allows for the user input
     Scanner szKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
     System.out.println("What is the text being encrypted? "); 
     userMessage = szKeyboard.nextLine() ; 
     //Removes all the spaces 
     userMessage = userMessage.strip() ;
     //A Random Key is Being Generated Everytime the Code is running
     for(int p = 0 ; p < userMessage.length() ; p++ )
     {
       //This is the random process, i have taken away 32 because it would give me output values that cannot be read from the ASCII table (1-31)
       iRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 223) ;
       //I added 32 making sure that i do not get a vlaue less than 32
       iSum = iRandom + 32 ; 
       //This number was changed to a binary value
       szBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(iSum) ;
       //The binary value was converted back into a char value
       letter = (binaryToChar(szBinary)); 
       //This is then connactnated to form the key
       key = key + letter ; 
     }
     //The key is stored into an array
     char[] keyArray = key.toCharArray() ;
     System.out.println("The Key is " + key) ; 
     //The message that is being incrypted it being stored into an cArray
     char [] messageArray = userMessage.toCharArray() ;
     System.out.println("Processing Data...") ;
     //This is used to save the message from the user into an external file 
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Message.txt", "UTF-8");
     writer.println(userMessage);
     writer.close();
//This saves the key into an external file so it can be recorded to encrypt and decrypt the message
     PrintWriter kWriter = new PrintWriter("Key.txt", "UTF-8");
     kWriter.println(key);
     kWriter.close();


     szKeyboard.close() ;

     findBinary(messageArray , keyArray) ;

    }

  public static char binaryToChar(String binary)
  {
    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2) ;
    return (char) decimal;
  }
}
```

**This is a code that I made, on how the Vernam Cipher works and I wanted to have a go for it myself, I wanted to know how I could have made it better and also how to fix my file writing problem where every time I will run this code, the contents within the files would be overwritten**. The Vernam Cipher works by taking a Message (userMessage) and applying a key to the message in the form of an XOR Gate. The key in my code is randomly generated and then both of these values are stored into an array. These then get taken to another function and then are converted into binary values, after they have been converted they are stored into another array and then taken to another function that applies the XOR gate to both the key and message (binary values). After this is done the result is stored into another array and is then is converted from Binary to ASCII Text. Please note, I am 16 Years of Age and have only started coding for 5-6 months and do not know much in-depth things yet.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. You can use `"Plaintext message".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to get a byte array for the text. Then you can use a random key generated using `SecureRandom.nextBytes(keyArray)` to generate a key. Your current code is not secure, as your key is not fully random and the value of the characters are not equally distributed over all bits of the byte. If you want to store binary ciphertext (or the key) as text, use base 64. Or simply store them as binary data.

Comment: Of course, to write to a new file each time, simply provide a different file name, maybe through the program arguments.

Comment: For the Vernam cipher, by the way, you'd normally generate and store / distribute the key in advance. Things like key generation should be performed in their own methods, of course. By the way, if your code is running correctly and if you don't have a specific question, the code is more at place @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com .